# Paint Supreme 3d not opening in Xubuntu 18.04

Tags: graphics, xubuntu, snap, paint

I installed "Paint Supreme 3d - Snap" using the software center in Xubuntu and while opening it only shows the splash screen and doesn't load. It doesn't open. How to make it open to use it. Please help.

Here is the error message when running program from command line:

```
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "gail" Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "atk-bridge"
```

Comment: can you start the app from the command line and see post any errors you see?

Comment: please tell me how to start it through command line?

Comment: open an terminal by pressing `ctrl`+`alt`+`t` and type `paintsupreme-3d`

Comment: The same problem is happening, even if I'm opening it through the terminal, only the first screen is showing after that the application doesn't load even waiting for a long time.

Comment: what kind of messages show up in the terminal window... that's what we want...

Comment: Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "gail"
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "atk-bridge"

Comment: Above mentioned shows up.

Comment: Is there any solution?

Comment: I have moved the message to your question... in the future it's best to add requested info by editing your question. I am working on an answer for you now :)

Comment: You could use the appimage downloadable at https://www.braindistrict.com/products/paintsupreme3d instead. I just tried installing the snap which doesn't work, the appimage does.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the error message, it looks like you have some missing modules that need to be installed: "gail" and "atk-bridge"

So we use apt-cache to locate the relevant packages:

```
apt-cache search gail
```

This gives us a few options, but the one we are looking for is:

> libgail-common - GNOME Accessibility Implementation Library -- common modules

And now the atk-bridge:

```
apt-cache search atk-bridge
```

Which returns something we want:

> libatk-bridge2.0-0 - AT-SPI 2 toolkit bridge - shared library

Now that we know what packages you need, time to install:

```
sudo apt install libgail-common libatk-bridge2.0-0
```

You should now have the required modules to run your program. Enjoy!